# Given $AB$, where $A$ and $B$ are $2×2$ matrices, find $BA-(BA)^{-1}$.

Tags: matrices, algebra-precalculus, matrix-equations, numerical-linear-algebra

Given that:
$$AB=\begin{pmatrix}
2020 & 1\\ 
2021 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$
where $A$ and $B$ are $2×2$ matrices, find $BA-(BA)^{-1}$.

I was given this problem in a math contest, but I didn't know how to approach it. My guess is that maybe it has something to do with the identity $(AB)^{-1}=B^{-1}A^{-1}$, but I don't know how I can get from $B^{-1}A^{-1}$ to $(BA)^{-1}$, nor how I can find $BA$ given $AB$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not sure if the solution is unique (or unique up to some multiplying factor and symmetry), but if you let $B$ be the identity, then $A=AB=BA$ and you can compute everything.

Comment: Ah, that's one good way to arrive at the correct answer. The question was actually multiple choice, so I would've gotten it right if I would've thought about this approach. Still, I'm curious if there is any way to prove rigourously that the solution is unique.

Comment: You could assume $A$ and $B$ commute, and then arrive at the same answer.

Comment: Call $X=BA-(BA)^{-1}$. Then $AXA^{-1}=AB-(AB)^{-1}$. Compute the latter, since you have $AB$. It turns out to be $2021 I$. Therefore, $AXA^{-1}=2021 I$. Multiply by $A^{-1}$ from the left and $A$ from the right. These commute with the identity, and therefore cancel. So $X=A^{-1}(2021 I )A=(2021 I)A^{-1}A=2021 I$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution is unique. Hint: Note that $\det(AB)=-1$ so we must also have $\det(BA)=-1$. Then write $BA = \pmatrix{a & b \\ c & d}$ and calculate $BA-(BA)^{-1}$. You realize that the resulting expression just involves the trace of $BA$ (thus the same as the trace of $AB$).

EDIT: Just realized that you get a general formula of the above phenomena in the following way: If $A$ and $B$ are invertible and $M=AB$ satisfies
$$ M^n + a_{n-1} M^{n-1} + \cdots a_0 {\bf 1} = 0 $$
then $M'=BA$ is a root of the same polynomial. In the present case you have:
$$  M^2 - ({\rm trace} M )\ M + \det(M) \ {\bf 1} = 
 M^2 - 2021 M - {\bf 1} = 0$$
or equivalently
$$ M - (M)^{-1} = 2021 \  {\bf 1}$$
and then $M'=BA$ verifies the same equation, thus yielding the wanted result.

Comment: Nice!${}{}{}{}$

Comment: But then I'm getting that $BA-BA^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix}
2021 & c-b\\
b-c & 2021
\end{pmatrix}$.  I suppose we somehow have to show that $b=c$ to arrive at $2021I$ ?

Comment: @greg234 , if you let $BA$ as in the answer, you should find that $BA - (BA)^{-1} = (a + d)I$, so you have a computational error somewhere.

Comment: You're right, my bad. Thanks for the help!